# SQL: Counting number of games for team from results page

Tags: sql, postgresql

Completely noob to SQL.
I have created the following table, which stores data on matches between two opponents and the points the winner got.

```
CREATE TABLE matches ( winner INT references players,
                       loser INT references players,
                       gamepoints INT);
```

I created the below VIEW to show standings:

```
CREATE VIEW standings as 
  select 
    players.id, 
    players.name, 
    count(matches.winner) as number_of_wins, 
    coalesce(sum(matches.gamepoints),0) as points
  from players left join matches 
  on players.id = matches.winner
  group by players.name, players.id
  order by number_of_wins desc, points desc;
```

I wish to add a column that will show how many games a player played. My problem is that games appear in both `matches.winner` and `matches.loser` columns, and I'm not sure how to aggregate them in the `standings` view.

Also, would you say that the `matches` table is normalized?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: changed `matches` content.

Comment: `winner` and `user` should **not** be defined as `serial`. Those are FK columns to players and thus should just be defined as `integer`. `serial` is **not** a "real" datatype.

Comment: Your table matches can't have two fields SERIAL unless they both are primary keys which I think it is not what you want.

Comment: A side note: you probably don't want winner/loser to be serial as that is an auto incrementing type and winner/loser should be foreign keys to your players table.

Comment: noted guys, thanks. I will change it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case you show there are only a few things that you should fix to be ok. Again for the problem you show.

**First:** Change the columns types of the table `matches` it shouldn't be `SERIAL` as it is an autoincrement type column (not a real type). Both columns are `foreign keys` and it should be `integer`, `int` or `bigint`

as

```
create table matches (
    winner bigint,
    loser bigint,
    gamepoints int,
    constraint fk_player_winner foreign key (winner) 
          references players(id),
    constraint fk_player_loser foreign key (loser) 
          references players(id)
);
```

**Second:** to know how many games a player did with the number of points you can create two subqueries one with the winners and one with the losers and join the two summing the values. The catch is that you have to decrease the gamepoints from the two:

```
select w.id, w.name, w.gp-l.gp as gamepoints, w.ng+l.ng
  from (select p.id, p.name, sum(m.gamepoints) gp, count(m.winner) as ng
          from players p inner join matches m 
                             on p.id=m.winner
         group by p.id, p.name ) w
        INNER JOIN
       (select p.id, p.name, sum(m.gamepoints) gp, count(m.loser) as ng
          from players p inner join matches m 
                             on p.id=m.loser
         group by p.id, p.name) l on w.id=l.id;
```

From it you create your view.

**Note:** maybe I'm being overkill with this two subqueries. It is possible to work out with a join between two `players` tables and a `matches`

See how it goes here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b6a4/4

Comment: Thanks a lot! It doesn't work very well though. For example, I have 8 players, which few played 2 games and few played 3 games, and it shows weird numbers on w.ng+l.ng (like 4 games played, for example). Also LEFT JOIN was needed. Still trying to figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: Unfortunatelly sqlfiddle went down. When it cames back I will take a look.

Comment: fixed it! thanks. it was the count- should've counted by the m.winner and m.loser rather the p.id. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Jorge Campos, this is the solution:

```
CREATE VIEW games_won as 
    select p.id, p.name, coalesce(sum(m.gamepoints),0) gp, count(m.winner) ng
    from players p left join matches m
    on p.id=m.winner
    group by p.id, p.name;

CREATE VIEW games_lost as 
    select p.id, p.name, count(m.loser) as ng
    from players p left join matches m 
    on p.id=m.loser
    group by p.id, p.name;

CREATE VIEW standings as 
    select w.id, w.name, w.ng as wins, w.ng+l.ng as matches, w.gp as gamepoints 
      from games_won w INNER JOIN games_lost l 
      on w.id=l.id
      order by wins desc, gamepoints;
```